# How to iterate over a list of strings and do pattern matching?

Tags: python

I have a list of strings like this:

```
lst= ['(', 'A', '(', 'B', '(', 'C', 'D', ')', '(', 'E', 'F', ')', ')', '(', 'G', 'H', ')', ')']
```

Joined together it looks like this:

```
(A(B(CD)(EF))(GH))
```

I want to traverse the list by element and store values into two lists like this: `['A','B','G']` `['B', 'C', 'E']`

I was trying to do this:

```
l1=[]
for i in range(len(lst)):
    if lst[i] == '(':
        l1.append(lst[i+1])
```

How can I break the computation such that it counts the number of opening and closing paranthesis and when the opening brackets get its closing bracket, then it adds the element after the next opening bracket, to get the result: `['A','B','G']` `['B', 'C', 'E']` ?

Comment: I don't understand your example.  It's not obvious what the mechanics are that causes A,B,G to be in one group but B,C,E in the other.  For example, why is F nowhere and B appears twice?  What are the rules exactly?

Comment: @John Zwinck I want to consider it like: A has 2 inner lists (B(CD)(EF)) and (GH), so I want to extract A, and first elements of those two inner lists. Similarly, B has two inner lists, (CD) and (EF), so I want to extract B, C, E.

Comment: u should use stacks to implement it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import re

string = ''.join(lst)
results = []

for match in re.finditer('\w\(', string):
    parens = 0
    substring = string[match.start():]
    results.append([substring[0]])
    for ii, ch in enumerate(substring):
        if ch == '(':
            parens += 1
            if parens == 1:
                results[-1].append(substring[ii+1])
        elif ch == ')':
            parens -= 1
            if parens < 0:
                break
```

Or without regex:

```
results = []

for jj in range(len(lst) - 1):
    if lst[jj] != ')' and lst[jj+1] == '(':
        parens = 0
        results.append([lst[jj]])
        substring = lst[jj:]
        for ii, ch in enumerate(substring):
            if ch == '(':
                parens += 1
                if parens == 1:
                    results[-1].append(substring[ii+1])
            elif ch == ')':
                parens -= 1
                if parens < 0:
                    break
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, the string represents a tree structure, with each node having a name and an arbitrary number of children. In s-expression style, this name is the first entry in a list (if there is a list; leaf nodes are only named).

```
(A
  (B
    (CD)
    (EF))
  (GH))
```

Within this tree, you want a printout of the nodes with multiple branches, including the names of those branches but not their contents. Parsing them is indeed easiest with a stack, possibly implicit in recursion.

```
from pprint import pprint

instr="(A(B(CD)(EF))(GH))"

nodes=[]
curnode=nodes
nodestack=[]
for char in instr:
    if char == '(':
        nodestack.append(curnode)
        curnode.append([])
        curnode=curnode[-1]
    elif char == ')':
        curnode=nodestack.pop()
    else:
        curnode.append(char)

# Show that the tree is now converted into list form
pprint(nodes, width=20)

def name(node):
    return node[0]
def branches(tree):
    if len(tree)>=3:
        yield map(name,tree)    # exploits that names are only 1 char
    for branch in tree[1:]:
        # search deeper also
        for subbranch in branches(branch):
            yield subbranch

for root in nodes:
    pprint(list(branches(root)))
```

It's certainly possible to merge the operations by printing branching nodes as they finish parsing (in the `')'` case).